# Android RecyclerView with CollapsingToolbarLayout smooth scroll issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I want to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout`with `RecyclerView`, like `Whatsapp`.

Here is the captured video : https://sendvid.com/0oi2lxx5

So when I scroll up it's okay, but when I scroll down it's not smooth. I want to scroll it smoothly with `RecyclerView`.

So here is my `profile_activity.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/profile_recyclerview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileactivity_appbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileactivity_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme3.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileactivity_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileactivity_fullimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profileactivity_appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white_48dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Drop ImageView's `app:layout_scrollFlags`, and see if that solves the issue. I think those flags contradict `app:layout_collapseMode`

Comment: if you try scroll via image its so smoothly but i cannot scroll like that via recyclerview. i think you understand

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well i will explain how to solve issue , now my layout is super smooth ;

> Actually i dont know how its solved , but ;

- i deleted all `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attributes.
- then added `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` attribute to `CollapsingToolbarLayout` , `ImageView` and `Toolbar`.
- And moved all elements before my `AppBarLayout` in xml.

My `activity_profile.xml` like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profileCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/profile_activity_progress" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ProgressBar android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/profile_activity_progress_edit" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<include layout="@layout/content_profile_edit"/>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profile_recyclerview"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/profileactivity_appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white_48dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/profileactivity_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme3.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileactivity_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/ColorPrimaryDark"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileactivity_fullimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the `content_profile_edit.xml` like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profile_edit_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profile_fragment_nested"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

   <!-- other views -->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how to pin toolbar and tablayout

Comment: @BincyBaby I don't quite understand you but can you check [cheesesquare releases](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/releases)

Comment: This method works fine, but if i wanted to pin toolbar and tablayout this will not work

Comment: @Bincy Baby dude I am willing to help you but you must provide some code and I must see what you have right now.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz some warning: if placed FAB above AppBarLayout, layout_anchor id will not be founded

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with RecyclerView and CollapsingToolbarLayout as well (did not collapse at all). Try using the current version 23.4.+ of recyclerview, appcompat and design if you're not doing already.

Comment: My problem isnt collapsing problem. If you watch the video when i scroll via touching collapsing image its super smooth.But when scrolling with recyclerview its not smooth as collapsing image view's.

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of the API's? Could be a bug that was fixed. I tried your layout and everything works fine.

Comment: i updated all of that to 23.4.0 version. But the same issue here.

Comment: yes, i updated recyclerview and changed scrollflags . Then my problem is gone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
google solve this issue in 26 api level .I spent my whole day finally I found this answer. For Demo You create  one android studio Scrolling Activity and do following changes upgrade all repository to 26 version and you will see this scrolling smoothly effect.
**/

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    **compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"**
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sandeep.quantauser"
        minSdkVersion 19
        **targetSdkVersion 26**
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-jakarta-commons-net-1.4.1.jar')
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.4.0.jar')
    **compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.2"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'**
}

**allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}**
```