# CollapsingToolbarLayout smooth scroll issue

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

While scrolling recyclerView with CollapsingToolbarLayout, Its not scrolling smooth. kindly suggest me, if any one knows

Comment: follow this link, Its working [smooth scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533372/android-recyclerview-with-collapsingtoolbarlayout-smooth-scroll-issue)

Comment: it would be great if you post some code too

Comment: tried that link..but its not working for me.. same i am getting smooth scroll issue. kindly suggest me, if you know best answer